# Is there a way to assign different colors to different authors in fixme?

Tags: color, fixme

I use [`fixme`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fixme) in `multiuser` mode, and would like different authors to have different colors (like the track changes feature in word). I know that I can use `todonotes`, but I like the `fixme` interface (and lack of reliance on `tikz`) better.

`fixme` colors notes by function (warning, error, etc) rather than by user. Is there some relatively easy way to make it do color by author?

Update: here's an M(nW)E

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[draft,inline,nomargin,index]{fixme}

\fxsetup{theme=color,mode=multiuser}
\FXRegisterAuthor{sv}{asv}{Me}
\FXRegisterAuthor{aa}{aaa}{Other} 

\begin{document}
\svnote{This is me} and \aanote{This is other}. 

What I'd like is something like

\textcolor{red}{Me: This is me} and \textcolor{green}{Other: This is other}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*EDIT* solution simplified and new alternative solution added, more comprehensive examples added

You can add a colour when registering the author by putting the color before the author tag:

```
\FXRegisterAuthor{sv}{asv}{\color{red}Me}
```

Here is a sample demonstrating various of the `fixme` formats, its list of fixmes and the index:

[image: Sample output]

[image: Sample output index]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[draft,inline,nomargin,index]{fixme}

\fxsetup{theme=color,mode=multiuser}
\FXRegisterAuthor{sv}{asv}{\color{red}Me}
\FXRegisterAuthor{aa}{aaa}{\color{green}Other} 

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\svnote{This is me} and \aanote{This is other}. 

Probably\sverror{A dire mistake.} a good thing. \aawarning*{Watch out!}{This
is trivial.} Oh no \aafatal{Die!}

\begin{svnote}[margin]{Explanation}
  A longer note that tries to explain something or other, but I can't
  remember what.
\end{svnote}

\listoffixmes

\printindex

\end{document}
```

For example, the inline notes are set via the `\FXLayoutInLine` which takes three arguments `Type` (error, etc.), `Note` and `Author`.  The third field `Author` is the last argument registered under the author, and is used unchanged in the note, so its color affects the rest of the text.

Alternatively you might just like to change the colour/background of the author identifier, keeping the color themes colours for the actually note text, as follows:

[image: Sample alternative output]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[draft,inline,nomargin,noindex]{fixme}

\fxsetup{theme=color,mode=multiuser}
\FXRegisterAuthor{sv}{asv}{\colorbox{red}{\color{black}Me}}
\FXRegisterAuthor{aa}{aaa}{\colorbox{green}{\color{black}Other}} 

\begin{document}

\svnote{This is me} and \aanote{This is other}. 

Probably\sverror{A dire mistake.} a good thing. \aawarning*{Watch out!}{This
is trivial.} Oh no \aafatal{Die!}

\begin{svnote}[margin]{Explanation}
  A longer note that tries to explain something or other, but I can't
  remember what.
\end{svnote}

\listoffixmes

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately this alternative version does not work with the index.